# Save video from QByteArray to MP4 QT/C++

Tags: qt, video, save, mp4, qbytearray

I downloaded the video from the Internet using QNetworkAccessManager, I ended up getting a QByteArray with an MP4 video file, how can I save it to my hard drive?

I tried to save it through QDataStream, but the resulting file could not be played.

I also read that you can try to do it through QMediaRecorder, but I haven’t found a way to add QByteArray there.

```
    QFile file(filename+"myfile.mp4");
    QDataStream ds(&file);
    if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        ds << data;
        file.close();
    }
```

I want the saved MP4 file to be played.

Comment: Why bother with the `QDataStream` at all?  Just do `file.write(data);`.

Comment: G.M. , Thank you! It`s work!